# How to handle transactions when it inserts a list in foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, .net, rollback

I have this method in my DAL which inserts all the objects in the list to a table in a foreach loop. But the problem is handling the transaction in such a way that if any of the items in the list cannot be inserted then whole process should be rolled back. Is there way to handle this or do I have to change the method?

```
public bool InsertEarnings(List<Earning> earningsList)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
    {
        string insertStatement = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SalaryTrans WHERE employee_id=@employee_id) " +
        "BEGIN INSERT INTO salaryTrans... " + 
        "ELSE BEGIN UPDATE SalaryTrans SET" ;

        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, sqlConnection))
        {
            SqlParameter paramEmployeeID = new SqlParameter("@employee_id", SqlDbType.Char);
            SqlParameter paramWorDays = new SqlParameter("@work_days", SqlDbType.Int);
            //


            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramEmployeeID);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramWorDays);
            //

            sqlConnection.Open();                    

            foreach (Earning earning in earningsList)
            {
                paramEmployeeID.Value = earning.EmployeeID;
                paramWorDays.Value = earning.WorkDays;
                //

                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look this sample, in the table coches all fields nvarchar(50)
IdCoche is the PrimaryKey, the table is empty

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Reading conection from App Settings
        //this insert values from 20 to 29
        ExecuteSqlTransaction(Settings.Default.Conexion,20);
        //this must insert values from 15 to 24
        //But at 20 a PrimaryKey infraction raise exception and rollback
        ExecuteSqlTransaction(Settings.Default.Conexion, 15);

    }
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString,int start)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");
        // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Coches] ([IdCoche],[Marca],[Modelo],[Version]) VALUES (@IdCoche,@Marca,@Modelo,@Version)";
        command.Parameters.AddRange(new SqlParameter[]{
                new SqlParameter("@IdCoche",""),
                new SqlParameter("@Marca",""),
                new SqlParameter("@Modelo",""),
                new SqlParameter("@Version","")
            });
        try
        {
            for (int i = start; i < start + 10; i++)
            {
                command.Parameters["@IdCoche"].Value = "IdCoche"+i.ToString();
                command.Parameters["@Marca"].Value = "Marca" + i.ToString(); ;
                command.Parameters["@Modelo"].Value = "Modelo" + i.ToString(); ;
                command.Parameters["@Version"].Value = "Version" + i.ToString(); ;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("10 records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is really inefficient because the query you are doing for the "if".

If each employee can only have one record, then the field employee_id should be unique, and with that, if you replace your query with "INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..." will be a magnitude faster (depending on your record count) and will not break if a row cannot be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

[In This link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1748759.aspx?How%20to%20rollback%20all%20transaction%20if%20insert%20command%20in%20a%20loop) they describe something that seems like what you are trying to do. Rather than using `SqlCommand` he suggests using `SqlTransaction` this way you can run your insert and if all succeeded use `transaction.Commit` else `transaction.Rollback`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you use a transaction initiated from C# code, it will fire up MSDTC which has a lot of overhead and should be avoided if possible.  If you have the opportunity, use a stored procedure that takes a [table parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), build and submit the table with a SQL Command and do the transactional controls at the database instead of using a distributed transaction coordinator session. I would also recommend using [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) syntax.